# May Zecher Machatzit Hashekel be given on Shabbat when Purim falls on it

Tags: halacha, shabbat, purim, gifts, orach-chaim

Some Jews have the minhag to give Zecher Machatzit Hashekel on Purim. My question is, is it permissible in Halacha to give this as a gift on Shabbat when purim falls on Shabbat or no?

Comment: Even the official Matanot Laevyonim isn't given on shabbat, and that's actually required.

Comment: The Rema mentions to give it by mincha before Purim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Also the real Machatzit Hashekel

Comment: @Heshy That is reasonable but do you have a source?

Comment: @Chatzkel see magen avraham

Comment: @DoubleAA just אין מקדישין Beitzah 5:2, nothing more specific